# Binding itemSource ListView in Mode = TwoWay

Tags: win-universal-app, template10

Sorry for my bad English. I tried to bind a list of Images in a list view's itemsource:

```
ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Images,Mode=TwoWay}"

In ViewModel I have a list of Images :

     public List<Image> Images
    {
        get { return _images; }
        set
        {
            _images = value;
            base.RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

With binding mode set to TwoWay, I have the following error:

```
Invalid binding path 'View Model.Reports': You can not associate the type 'System.Collections.Generic.List (posytron.epart.uwp.Models.DOM.Report)' to 'System.Object' without a converter
```

If I set binding mode to OneWay it works!

I have already developed a converter to convert a boolean to a visibility attribute.

What should the converter contain? Can someone help me? Why do I have this error?

Thank you!!

Comment: Please post the ListView xaml and model class. Without that it's difficult to give solution

Comment: @LovetoCode +1, Also why do you need TwoWay in Listview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not using Tempalte 10, only a normal UWP app to test your problem, and I think I've reproduced your problem.
[image]

The error message is a little different possible due to the Model of Template 10, but I think the error is the same.

> If I set binding mode to OneWay it works!

If you use OneWay mode of {x:Bind}, your `ListView`'s `ItemSource` is the binding target, and your `List<Image> Images` in the ViewModel is the binding source. Obviously your source is a list of `Image` controls. The type of `ItemSource` is System.Object, and the binding source here is a List of type Image control. By default, a data item is displayed in the ListView as the string representation of the data object it's bound to. So when xaml can't recognize this string, it will directly use implementation of ToString method to return the type name and show it on the item. In a word, `ItemSource` as binding target has done the work of converting types.

But when using TwoWay mode, ItemSource is binding target and also the binding source, so is the `List<Image> Images`. It works well in the pattern "ItemSource = binding target", the reason I've explained upper, but if the "ItemSource = binding source", it will not automatically convert the System.Object type to your List type. Also you can say, your doesn't provide a converter to converter  System.Object type to your needed type.

But I don't think you need TwoWay binding here. TwoWay binding Updates either the target or the source object when either changes. When the binding is created, the target property is updated from the source. From your code, I can't see you can change Image controls in the Items to update the source List. If you just want to dynamic add or remove or edit the items in the ListView, you can use OneWay mode here and change the List in the code behind.

Comment: Thank you! It 'just that the error  seemed to say the opposite . The error is : You can not associate the type System.Collections.Generic.List (posytron.epart.uwp.Models.DOM.Report) to System.Object . Would not it be more correct the error  You can not associate the type System.Object to System.Collections.Generic.List (posytron.epart.uwp.Models.DOM.Report) ?